# An idiom meaning a thing that was costly to create and is now costly to maintain.

Tags: idiom-requests

Example usage:

> This project is something of [noun] - we spent six months building it, and now it's functional, but there are several things that require tweaking and maintenance to make it really professional.

I don't necessarily mean that the project is overall a waste of resources - just that it's costly.

Comment: Like an aircraft carrier, which may be useful but is expensive to build and maintain?  Or a boondoggle like an amusement park that doesn't bring in enough money to cover the extensive ongoing costs of maintenance and personnel?

Answer (score 2):

> [**white elephant:**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/white+elephant)
>
> 1. An expensive item that is troublesome or useless.
>
> The term comes from a story about the king of Siam, who was said to
>   have given an albino elephant, considered sacred, to a member of the
>   court whom he disliked, knowing that taking care of the animal would
>   exhaust the person's fortune.
>
> *At first, Eve was excited to inherit the farm, but it soon proved to be a white elephant she couldn't afford*.

Maybe it's suitable; something close to your search.

Comment: What I don't like about white elephant, is that it implies that the thing is inherently useless. This isn't the case in my situation. The project has value, but is costly to maintain/get to releasable quality.

Answer (score 1):

[Making a rod for your own back](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-rod-for-your-own-back):

Essentially, providing a solution to a problem, but one which creates further future problems to maintain it.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

> [***cost somebody dear***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cost+dear)
>
> if something that someone does, especially something stupid, costs
> them dear, it causes them a lot of problems
>
> ***Example:***
>
> Later that year he attacked a photographer, an incident that cost him dear.

***Usage:***

This project ***costs us dear*** - we spent six months building it, and now it's functional, but there are several things that require tweaking and maintenance to make it really professional.